# printing a boolean value in c++

Tags: c++

When I run this simple code,

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
      bool digit(true);
      std::cout << digit << " " << ~digit << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
1 -2
```

I was expecting 1 and 0 (for true and false). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Try to cout !(digit).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`~` performs bitwise negation. The operand is promoted (in this case) to `int`, and all the bits are inverted. 1 has a binary representation of `00....001`, so this gives the binary value `11....110`, which is interpreted (on most modern computers) as -2.

Use `!` for logical negation.

Comment: aah... that `bool` casting to `int` before inversion was the game here. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi - that `bool` **converts** to `int`; there is no **cast** in that code. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 4):

`~` is the bitwise not (or bit inversion) operator.  The logical not operator is '!'.

```
    cout << !digit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a logical not operator is '!'.You may try this;

```
cout << !(digit);
```

**EDIT:-**

Although I know its late but trying to improve my answer, `~` is the bitwise not operator. So if you write something like `~1000` then it would result out to be `0001`

Comment: Thanks :). yes... it does produce ` 1 0` as expected with !digit... but I am interested more in what's I am missing with the `~` operator.

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi:- Actually ~ performs bitwise negation. So all the operand is gets used as and hence alll the bits get inverted

Answer (score 1):

Essentially:

```
 1 -> 00000001
~1 -> 11111110
```

Answer (score 0):

```
4 bits integer
1 -> 0001

find the complement by adding 1
0001 + 0001 = 0010 = 2

the complement is -2
```